# What is the area of oblique line $\frac{x^3+2x^2+x+1}{x^2+2x+1}\,dx$?

Tags: calculus, integration, asymptotics, area

For area between $x=0$ and $x=\infty$

Is it $\int_{0}^\infty\frac{x^3+2x^2+x+1}{x^2+2x+1}dx$?

Or something like $\int_{0}^\infty F(x)-G(x)$

While $G(x)$ being oblique asymptote?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HINT**

\begin{align*}
\frac{x^{3} + 2x^{2} + x + 1}{x^{2} + 2x + 1} & = \frac{x^{2}(x+1) +(x^{2} + 2x + 1) - x}{(x+1)^{2}}\\\\\
& = \frac{x^{2}}{x+1} + 1 - \frac{x}{(x+1)^{2}}\\\\
& = \frac{(x^{2} - 1) + 1}{x+1} - \frac{(x+1) - 1}{(x+1)^{2}} + 1\\\\
& = x - 1 + \frac{1}{x+1} - \frac{1}{x+1} + \frac{1}{(x+1)^{2}} + 1\\\\
& = x + \frac{1}{(x+1)^{2}}
\end{align*}

Can you take it from here?

Comment: I integrated last statement for x=0 and x=$\infty$ and result is $\infty$. Is it correct?

Comment: Yes, that's the point. Since the integrand is not bounded, then it is not Riemann integrable.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what "Or something else like $\displaystyle \int_0^\infty F(x)- G(x)\,dx$ while $G(x)$ being oblique asymptote" means or what it has to do with this integral!

But for the integral:
$\displaystyle \int_0^\infty \frac{x^3+2x^2+x+1}{x^2+2x+1}\,dx=\int_0^\infty x\,dx+\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{(x+1)^2}\,dx$.

That first integral, $\displaystyle \int_0^\infty x\,dx$ does not exist so the stated integral does not exist.

For the indefinite integral, to integrate $\dfrac{1}{(x+ 1)^2}$ let $u=x+1$ so that $du=dx$ and the integral becomes $$\displaystyle \int \frac{du}{u^2}= \int u^{-2}du= -u^{-1}+ C= -\frac{1}{x+ 1}+C$$ so $$\int \frac{3x+ 2x^2+ x+ 1}{x^2+ 2x+ 1}\,dx= \int x\,dx+\int \frac{1}{(x+1)^2}\,dx= \frac{1}{2}x^2- \frac{1}{x+1}+ C$$

But, as before, that has no limit as $x$ goes to $\infty$.

Comment: It was area between x=0 and x=$\infty$ so it's definite integral actually. But that integral doesn't exist so what is answer? There isn't any area or is it infinite?

Answer (score 0):

The curve has area contributed from two parts:
[image]

$$ \int_0^\infty x\,dx+\int _0^{\infty}\frac{1}{(x+1)^2}\,dx$$

The second part converges, evaluates to 1. First part function is monotonous unbounded, its area diverges.

$$ \text{ diverging part +   1}  \to \text{diverges}  $$

A definite finite value of second part only

Comment: How a finite value of total area can exist when x=$\infty$ ?